# MaterialBottomTab not appearing on ios simulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

This is my file that I am trying to create a demo of a bottom-tab. The problem is, I only get a blank page, no sign of a bottom tab. There is no error that I can point to. I don't know what is causing it, I deleted and reinstalled the relevant packages a few times already, but had no results. Any help is much appreciated.

````
import React from 'react'
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs"
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()
const EmptyScreen = () => {
    return <View>

    </View>
}
export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Tab.Navigator
        barStyle={{backgroundColor: "black",
        paddingBottom: 48 }}
        initialRouteName= "feed">
            
        <Tab.Screen
            name = "feed"
            component = {EmptyScreen}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
            name = "Profile"
            component = {EmptyScreen}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
            name = "Add"
            component = {EmptyScreen}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
            name = "Settings"
            component = {EmptyScreen}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </View>
  )
}```




And this is the package.json file in case anyone needs it to reproduce the situation.

```{
  "name": "academical",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.3",
    "expo": "^46.0.9",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "firebase": "^8.10.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  }
}```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Wrap the Tab.Navigator with a NavigationContainer and set independent = {}.